# Doctrine filter by relationship combination

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I would really appreciate any input on this one as it's been a bit of a head scratcher for me.

We have 4 entities related to products, Category > Product > Variant > VariantProperty.

VariantProperty is a key value pair, ie 'Colour' => 'Blue'. Products have many Variants and Categories have many Products.

I'm trying to think of a way from the Product repository to find Products that contain a Variation with a matching set of VariantProperties. Criteria won't work due to how it works with relationship depth afaik and using a repository method I can filter to find one product that has a variant with one matching VariantProperty.

I can't think how to filter by a set of VariantProperties though. Tried doing it in code but with the amount of variations we have I end up using 100mb+ and taking far too long.

Category has a ManyToMany relationship to Product
Product has a OneToMany relationship to Variants
and Variants has a OneToMany relationship to VariantProperties.

This is done due to the varying type of properties per variant.

My only other thought was to find a matching set of VariantProperties grouped by the Variant ID and going from there, however that seems somewhat hacky to me.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this in the category repository? If you want to find products, you should work in the product repository. Anyway can't you simply do a query in DQL with proper left joins and where conditions on variant properties? Am I missing something?

Comment: My apologies, I meant Product repository. Corrected that now. I'm sure I can, I'm probably missing something but I can't think of the best way to structure the query so that it only returns products with a variant that matches a set of VariantProperty entities. ie I need to find a product with a variant that has a relationship to a VariantProperty entity matching 'Colour' => 'red' and an entity matching 'Width' => '8088'. I'm probably missing something obvious at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only feasible way that I can think of is a JOIN (no left) to the variants that are of your interest, combined with a `GROUP BY product` and a `HAVING COUNT(variant) = :expetedVariants`.

I'll try to explain with a piece of pseudo-DQL, filtering by 2 variants:

```
SELECT p
FROM product
JOIN variant
JOIN variantProperty
WHERE 
    (variantProperty.name = variantName1 AND variantProperty.value = variantValue1)
    OR
    (variantProperty.name = variantName2 AND variantProperty.value = variantValue2)
GROUP BY product
HAVING COUNT(variantProperty) = 2
```

Comment: +1 This was exactly what was needed, thanks. I have an implementation of it that I'm happy to share if it will help others.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this in the product repository?

```
 public function findByProperties($properties)
{
$qb=$this->createQueryBuilder('prod')
  ->addSelect('var', 'varpro') //can remove if you don't want to hydrate these objects
  ->join('prod.variants', 'var')
  ->join('var.variantProperties', 'varpro');

$expr=$qb->expr()->orX('1=0');
$i=0;
foreach ($properties as $name => $value) {
  $expr=$qb->expr()->orX($expr, $qb->expr()->andX('varpro.propertyName = :name'.$i, 'varpro.propertyValue = :value'.$i));
  $i++;
}

$qb->andWhere($expr);

$i=0;
foreach ($properties as $name => $value) {
  $qb->setParameter(':name'.$i, $name);
  $qb->setParameter(':value'.$i, $value);
  $i++;
}

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
}
```